# Ajax driven timeline-style blog (in Drupal)

Tags: ajax, drupal, blogs, timeline

I have created a blog in drupal using CCK and taxonomy.
I wish to display my posts in a timeline, according to the posted date (using views).
So far I have created a listing of the post titles on a timeline.
I now want to display the posts using ajax, wherein clicking on a post title will load the content of that node on the same page. Going ahead I'll add each fetched node into a ul tag and thus create a carousel kind of display of all fetched posts so far.

Whats the best way of achieving this, considering that I have enough knowledge to create a custom module.

Here's where I got my idea from.
http://www.jvm-neckar.de

Answer (score 2):

Try the aptly named http://drupal.org/project/timeline project. I used it long time ago... its a nifty module and you can visualize your various posts on a scrollable timeline. Posts that are frequent will be together and posts that are apart (in time) will be apart -- its all scaled accurately. It has integration with views, of course.

I'm not sure about whether it will meet your exact requirements. Check out an example here:
http://simile.mit.edu/timeline/examples/jfk/jfk.html

Comment: Hey I remember seeing this long time back while searching for something else! Thanks! but the thing is I wouldn't be having posts as frequently, and I want to make it on my own, so its as flexible as I want it to be :P

Comment: Hey, I got something setup to do exactly what I want!
Will post the link if/when I get it online